# Как создать гибкую схему таблиц для хранения сообщений из разных чатов?

Tags: mysql, data-structures

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в следующей ситуации:

Есть два вида API где хранятся истории сообщений, это [**Zopim**](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/chat/chats) и [**Chat2Desc(импортировать в Postman)**](https://www.getpostman.com/collections/c598e71f85fd72404ff6) . Пока эти два но могут потом и другие появится.

И моя ДБ с таблицей `users`:

```
Table users
id , email, phone, ...
```

В **Zopim** пользователи идентифицируются через **email**, a в **Chat2Desc** через **телефон**. Для меня эти два поля важны, какой бы чат  не был и сколько бы их не было.

То есть если я получаю емайл либо телефон пользователя в сообщениях, то делаю запрос в свою базу (`table users`) для идентифицирования своего пользователя.

Да и в принципе даже структура чатов не важна, я данные как нибудь да выберу.А вот как их правильно сохранить , да так чтоб у меня была одна структура для всех .

И вот что я придумал:
[image: DB Schema Design]

**Разъяснение:**

Таблица `chats` (Данные для чата) :

1. `client_id`   - указывает на `id` таблицы `chat_clients`
2. `duration`    - длительность чата
3. `system_type` - хранит имя чата (`Zopim`, `Chat2Desc`, ... )
4. `created_at`  - дата создания

Таблица `chat_clients` (сведений об пользователей которые были в чате):

1. `assigned_data` - те инициалы под которыми пользователи были в чате
2. `is_agent`      - (0 | 1): 1 => мой пользователь, 0 => не мой
3. `users_id`      - `id` пользователя. Содержит либо `id` из таблицы `users` либо пустой.
4. `bean_module`   - неважно (сведение о моём пользователе)
5. `unique_col`    - Тут будет либо email (из Zopim) либо телефон (из Chat2Desc, Либо думаю хранить `id` таблицы `users`).Будет гарантировать уникальность значений.

Связка `users_id + unique_col` уникальна (`UNIQUE KEY user_id_unique_col_UQ (user_id,unique_col)`)

Таблица `chat_messages`:

1. `text`      - текст сообщения.
2. `client_id` - указывает на `id` таблицы `chat_clients`
3. `chat_id`   - указывает на `id` таблицы `chats`
4. `file_id`   - указывает на `id` таблицы `chat_files`
5. `transport` - значение будет для Chat2Desc (Viber, WhatsApp ,...), для Zopim ,чтоб не пустовал , Zopim

Таблица `chat_files` Сведения о переданных файлах в чате.Aналогичных таблиц может быть может нет для хранения дополнительной инфы.

> **Доп инфо**: В дальнейшем собираюсь для каждого пользователя выводит
>   историю сообщений.

**Вопрос:**
Как создать гибкую схему таблиц для хранения сообщений из разных чатов ?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: В чём, собственно, проблема? Что не получается? Что не работает? Какую ошибку вы наблюдаете?

Comment: @sanmai ошибку пока не наблюдаю .Не нравится сложность структуры

Comment: Если нет ошибки или конкретной проблемы, то ваш вопрос следует закрыть. Оффтопик здесь.

Comment: @sanmai Проблема в сложности структуры на мой взгляд.И в дальнейшем может привести к побочным эффектам.Закрыт или нет я как нибудь определюсь

Comment: Каким конкретно эффектам? Опишите все детали в вопросе.

Comment: @sanmai В вопросе все есть.Если бы я мог все варианты написать то сам бы решил свою задачу.По этому и написал то что вижу на первых порах.

Comment: Если вы пишите что видите на первых порах, то это автоматически означает что вы не видите все. Негативные побочные эффекты в вопросе не указаны, хотя вы знаете что они могут быть. Если вы знаете что-то, что может помочь дать ответ, то это нужно добавить в вопрос. Что тут непонятно?

Comment: @sanmai Если бы я мог описать такие проблемы ,то не задавал бы вопрос в таком широком формате

Comment: Может тогда стоит поменять цель вопроса? Не создать другую структуру, а описать возможные проблемы в указанной.

Comment: @sanmai Ваша позиция ясна,спасибо.Дайте и другим высказаться.
`Может тогда стоит поменять цель вопроса?` не стоит. Меня волнует лишь данная ситуация,которую я впринципе подробно описал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Любые проблемы по созданию БД нужно разбивать на две части:

1. Нужно выделить то, что уже есть. Выделить данность, реальность. То, что вы не можете изменить. То есть, выделить структуру внешних данных.
2. Нужно выделить то, что вы хотите получить. Желаемый вид и форма.

У вас в структуре всё в одной куче. И материальное представление, и логический вид. Вам нужно выделить отдельные структуры под хранения данных из каждой отдельной системы чатов, которые вы поддерживаете. Так как структуры от­личаются ключами привязки к пользователям, это должны быть разные структуры. Нет, ко­не­чно, можно всё сделать в одной таблице, но тут вы ничего не приобретёте, но очень про­иг­ра­ете в сложности структуры. Если вам нужно делать уникальный ключ по двум ко­лонкам, то вы что-то делаете не так.

Затем нужно выделить то, что вы хотите получить. Значить вам нужна какая-то таблица свя­зки чатов и пользователей, и таблицы связки чатов в основной таблице и чатов в мате­риаль­ных таблицах. Если нужно хранить сообщения в каждом чате для быстрого доступа, то лучше будет это сделать явно, в отдельной таблице, не связанной с материальным пред­став­лением. Так сообщения будут храниться два раза, но вы не будете связаны материальным пред­став­лением после импорта сообщений, и ваш код получения данных из БД будет много проще и надёжней.

В современном мире нет смысла пытаться оптимизировать число таблиц в БД: если у вас их будет десять или сотня, само по себе это нисколько не повлияет на скорость работы с БД. Другое дело что сложная для понимания структура БД будет отнимать ваше время и на первоначальную разработку, и на дальнейшую поддержку. Если траты вашего времени можно избежать, то это следует сделать.

Сама сложная структура БД может представлять и сложность при масштабировании. Например, шардинг и уникальные индексы идут по разные стороны улицы: вы не можете использовать шардинг одновременно с уникальными индексами. То же можно сказать про скорость вставки записей: уникальные индексы ей не помогают.

Comment: у меня вопрос к вам тогда, а если например в одной колоночной таблице (postgres) 100 миллионов записей с уникальным id (primary key - decimal(18,0)) и выборка идет по primary и еще одному varchar параметру и по сотне за раз IN (1,2,3), это нормально хранить в таком виде? Я имею ввиду в реляционной таблице. Или есть смысл перекинуть это все в nosql-jsonb, так как возможность есть.

Comment: `У вас в структуре всё в одной куче. И материальное представление, и логический вид ` Чтобы сохранить все значения из разных сервисов ,это понятно, надо поотдельности хранить их.Но в любом чате есть общие значения ,которые мне и нужн,остальные для меня избыточны.

Comment: И лучше, по моему, копаться в 3-4 таблицах чем в 10- 20 ... Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Сергей в шапке странице есть кнопка "задать вопрос" - рекомендую

Comment: Лучше вообще не копаться в таблицах. По вашей схеме, вроде как без избыточности, копаться придется точно. Выбирайте: или простая и понятная БД с некоторой избыточностью, или сложная и непонятная без избыточности.

Comment: Понимаете в виде дампа я и так в отдельной ДБ храню все таблицы , колонки и их значения.Это на тот случай если моя логика окажется ошибочной.

Comment: Нет, не понимаю. Вы хотите чтобы структура была менее сложная, или вы хотите чтобы в ней не было никакого дублирования? Одно другому противоречит.

Comment: По возможности и то и другое.

Comment: Каким образом можно получить и то, и другое сразу? Хотя бы один пример сколько-нибудь сложной структуры можете придумать чтобы там было и то, и другое сразу?

Comment: Не берите в голову. Спасибо за ответ и продуктивную дискуссию.